# is it possible to run multiple static initializers or similar across partial declarations of a class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Our control system has a lot of data files that have specific versions. The data files are "append only", so a higher version will always contain a superset of the definitions in the earlier versions.

In order to avoid "magic numbers" in our code, we have created a code generator that take a piece of data and turns it into a C# class file. I have a pretty large class library containing pretty much only such files. This results in much more readable code and some additional compiler checks because type previously risky type casting can now be part of the generated code, so that users of the library consume their correct subtypes directly.

However, the question comes up what data file version was used in the latest version of the class library. I would like every class file to "contribute" to a global list. If static constructors were automatically run, this is what I would do:

```
// GlobalConstants.cs (not generated)
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    public static List<string> Lst = new List<string>(); 
    static void AddVersionInfo(string mod)
    {
        Lst.Add(mod);
    }
}

// Motor.cs
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    // Generated from Motor metadata
    public class MotorUtil
    {            
        public const int SomeConst1 = 2;
        static MotorUtil()
        {
            AddVersionInfo("<Motor version info>");
        }
    }
}

// Tank.cs
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    // Generated from Tank metadata        
    public class TankUtil
    {
        public const int SomeConst1 = 2;
        public const int SomeConst2 = 3;
        public const int SomeConst3 = 5;
        static TankUtil()
        {
            AddVersionInfo("<Tank version info>");
        }
    }
}
```

If static constructors where run automatically, this would result in every generated file (tank.cs, motor.cs, boiler.cs etc) being added to the list, which could be inspected by a tool.

A compile time MEF, if you like.

Unfortunately. If I print out contents of "Lst", then it's always an empty list because the static constructors haven't run.

These .cs files come from different parties and the author of GlobalConstants.cs should not be required to know about them.
My question is: Is there a way in which I can generate this code so that one can add generated .cs files at will and they will appear in the "Lst" list?

Comment: You have not created any instances of your enclosed classess MotorUtil and TankUtil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static constructors for each of your nested classes won't run until those nested classes are referenced for the first time.  That hasn't happened in your above code, hence the list is empty.

One way I could imagine you might be able to do this would be for a static initializer in the `GlobalConstants` class to use reflection to find the nested classes.

Or maybe you could add a static field in each partial class file that references the nested class, forcing its static constructor to run:

```
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    // Generated from Tank metadata        

    private static TankUtil _unusedTankUtilField = new TankUtil();

    public class TankUtil
    {
        public const int SomeConst1 = 2;
        public const int SomeConst2 = 3;
        public const int SomeConst3 = 5;
        static TankUtil()
        {
            AddVersionInfo("<Tank version info>");
        }
    }
}
```

Also I don't believe the order of execution of static initializers across partial class files is strictly defined (presumably corresponds to the order they are processed by the compiler).  So I'd suggest you make your "AddVersionInfo" method responsible for initializing the list:

```
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    public static List<string> Lst; 
    static void AddVersionInfo(string mod)
    {
        if (Lst == null) Lst = new List<string>();
        Lst.Add(mod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your concerns regarding the static initialization seemed justified. Do you know if there is any chance that a "too smart" compiler will remove the unused field, thereby causing the static initialization to not run? Resharper certainly thinks that it can be removed.

Comment: @Tormod, interesting question, I don't believe either a compiler or a JITter would remove fields in this way, but I don't have a reference to prove it.  If you're concerned you could use reflection instead, provided you're not in a partial trust environment (`Type.GetNestedTypes` to find all the nested types or use an attribute as suggested in one of the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

For a somewhat simpler syntax, you could do it using attributes instead of static classes.

If you define an attribute;

```
public class UtilVersionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _versionInfo;

    public UtilVersionAttribute(string versionInfo) { _versionInfo = versionInfo; }

    public string VersionInfo { get { return _versionInfo; } }
}
```

...you can just attribute the classes instead...

```
public static partial class GlobalConstants
{
    [UtilVersion("<Motor version info>")]
    public class MotorUtil
    {
        public const int SomeConst1 = 2;
    }
}
```

...and update it when the program first starts using...

```
static void UpdateVersionInfo(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        var attribute = 
            type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (UtilVersionAttribute), true)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if(attribute != null)
            GlobalConstants.Lst.Add((attribute as UtilVersionAttribute).VersionInfo);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    UpdateVersionInfo(assembly);

    GlobalConstants.Lst.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

...for a complete list of your versions.

MEF may help here too, you may want to consider using it instead of implementing a "light version". Even your static constructor registrations are runtime registrations, not compile time, so I'm not sure of your reasons for staying away from it.

Comment: Very interesting. I haven't done much reflection, but I should definitely reach for it more after it became easier with .NET 4. I wasn't exploring this avenue at all.

Comment: I implemented this solution. Then I decided on using a base class with version info and retrieve the individual substypes using reflection. The key was really to iterate on type level using reflection and interact with the different modules. I don't do it as part of static initialization, but lazily evaluated on demand when retrieving the versions. Thanks again.